# Changing color ramp in R

Tags: r, color-ramp, title

I am trying to plot water quality by 3 districts of a nation. I have plot the map according to Biological Oxygen Demand value from the table as shown below:-
[image]

The code I used is as shown:-

```
install.packages("cartography")
install.packages("sf")
install.packages("tidyverse")
library(cartography)
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)
setwd("C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/IEM")
KathmanduWaterQlty<-st_read("KathmanduValley.shp")
View(KathmanduWaterQlty)
ggplot(data=KathmanduWaterQlty)+geom_sf(aes(fill=BOD), color="black")+
scale_colour_brewer(palette="1") +
xlab("Longitute")+ ylab("Latitude")+
ggtitle("Biological Oxygen Demand of Water in Kathmandu Valley")
```

Though I got the map displayed but the color is not appealing to look at. How can this be changed to different color type that looks more pleasing to look at. Also, how can title be centered and x-axis and y-axis be removed?
The final displayed is:-
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using `ggplot2`, you should have a look to:

1. `scale_fill_*` options. There is plenty of options on `ggplot2`, and you can create your own with `scale_fill_gradientn()`. See https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/index.html#scales
2. For modifyying theme elements, have a look to the `theme` possibilites: https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/theme.html.

A good place to get answers on `ggplot2` is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ggplot2

```r
library(dplyr)
# An example data, use yours
KathmanduWaterQlty <- giscoR::gisco_get_nuts(country = "Italy", nuts_level = 2) %>%
  mutate(BOD = sample(1:5, 21, replace = TRUE))

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = KathmanduWaterQlty) +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = BOD), color = "black") +
  xlab("Longitute") +
  ylab("Latitude") +
  ggtitle("Biological Oxygen Demand of Water in Kathmandu Valley") +
  # Change palette
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours = c("yellow","red", "blue")) +
  theme(
    axis.text = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks = element_blank(),
    plot.title = element_text(size=13, hjust = .5, face = "bold")
  )
```

[image]

Comment: ,Thanks it worked but can't we display name of the each polygon in map using some sorts of codes.

Comment: Use `geom_sf_text()` see examples: https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/ggsf.html